# Install Ubuntu 13.10 in dual boot with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, 13.10, windows-8

I have a laptop with installed Windows 8.1 x64. I want to intstall Ubuntu 13.10 (x64 of cause) in dual boot with it.
I've made bootable USB stick (using unetbootin) with Ubuntu and tried to boot with it. It boots fine, and allows me to choose language and asks whether I want to install Ubuntu or just boot it. But if I select any ot these options, it shows black screen and hangs. I've been waiting about 15 minutes for it, but nothing happened. Light of USB stick indicates that my laptop was not trying to read from it that time.

I switched off EFI in BIOS, switched AHCI/SATA modes, burned ISO image to DVD and still same effect.

This topic can be called a duplicated, but I have't find what it duplicates. In other topics people asked what will happen if they update Windows 8 to 8.1 having already dual boot and I have installed Windows 8.1 and want to install Ubuntu alongside with it

Did I miss something?

Comment: I sense there is something wrong with your usb drive. Can you try to use this on your Windows system? http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: I also used it, but didn't mentionet as I cannot remember app's name. Effect was same to described. I tried to use DVD instead of USB, so USB is not the main problem, I guess

Comment: Well, that black screen appears whenever I have Secure Boot activated. If I install with it desactivated, and UEFI on, I am able to install it right away. Sometimes it goes black also, but if I restart it will boot.

Comment: msinfo32 indicates that Secure Boot is not supported by my PC. Also, it states that BIOS is in legacy mode

Comment: What is your graphics card?

Comment: AMD radeon 7660G. But my CPU (AMD A10) also has integrated graphic adapter - HD 7600M

Comment: I tried to boot slax and Elementary OS, with the same effect - black screen and no effect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1):

If your flash drive boots to the splash screen, you've just passed a major step. This means that your BIOS is set correctly. The problem could now lie in the installation media. I suggest remaking the USB drive with Universal USB Installer, or try a different USB drive. Make sure that the USB drive is formatted to FAT32. Also try to check your installation media, or just download the ISO again. If push comes to shove, you could always try burning the ISO to a CD or DVD and boot from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: well, I've asked on russian-speaking forum, and they adviced to update my BIOS. That wored and I managed to install Ubuntu. But I cannot boot it as Grub does not appear and Windows boots as usual. As I've said in my question I tried different flash drives, different ISOs and even burned it on DVD