# Is it possible to use ubuntu alongside windows 8 without any bootloader(grub, win8 etc.)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I want to use ubuntu alongside my windows 8, but when i press the power button, i do not want to see any bootloader, i want windows 8 automatically begins, and when i want to use ubuntu, i want to use BIOS settings or recovery button(on my Lenovo) to switch to.

An example:
Power on - Windows 8 begins
Power off and pushing onekey recovery button and choosing operating system( for ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu 13.10 in dual boot with Windows 8.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372907/install-ubuntu-13-10-in-dual-boot-with-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, if your computer has UEFI.

1. Set Windows default OS in UEFI settings.
2. Set Ubuntu default OS in grub.
3. Set grub to be hidden.

That works for me, but it may depend on UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMware or virtual box, and load any OS inside the VMware. Third party software not showing in boot loader so when ever you want to load Ubuntu or any other OS just  run VMware. But the thing is you need to run  windows, so it just like a parallel way run other OS in windows.    Thanks

Comment: Thank you but Pilot6's way has worked for me :)